# Bindkey persist between sessions

Tags: zsh

I am using the `bindkey` command that comes with zsh to change key bindings.

Any time I close my terminal session and open a new one, all the changes I made by executing `bindkey` commands are gone. How can I make them persist between terminal sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the current configuration to a file with

```
bindkey -L > ~/.zsh_bindkey
```

And then load this config from your startup file `~/.zshrc` by including the following line:

```
source ~/.zsh_bindkey
```

Be aware, that there are multiple keymaps (list via `bindkey -l`). If you have customized more than the `main` keymap, you need to save these too, e.g. for the `command` keymap issue

```
bindey -M command -L >> ~/.zsh_bindkey
```

An alternative approach would be to start from a predefined keymap (e.g. `bindkey -v` for the vi-like-bindings) and do your modifications afterwards. Put both in your `~/.zshrc` file.